# SIGSEGV Crash in thread 1, very small stack trace

Tags: ios, iphone

Recently our released app have crashed several times with a stack trace that contain very little information to what the root cause can be. According to the crash log, the crash happens in thread 1, but this thread only have two calls. Could it be that the real problem is still in the main thread 0?

Could anyone suggest the best approach to find the background problem?

```
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,2
Process:             App [159]
Version:             0813 (1.3.2)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-08-16 16:51:48.114 +0200
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.2 (11D257)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  1

Thread 0:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001924901d0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                           0x0000000189026d94 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1748
2   UIKit                           0x0000000189026610 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 164
3   UIKit                           0x0000000188f3afdc -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 344
4   QuartzCore                      0x0000000188b2c254 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 180
5   QuartzCore                      0x0000000188b26e1c CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 296
6   QuartzCore                      0x0000000188b26cd4 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 28
7   QuartzCore                      0x0000000188b2655c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 276
8   QuartzCore                      0x0000000188b26300 CA::Transaction::commit() + 420
9   QuartzCore                      0x0000000188b1fc34 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 76
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185f37854 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
11  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185f34adc __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
12  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185e75df4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
13  GraphicsServices                0x000000018bb5dc08 GSEventRunModal + 164
14  UIKit                           0x0000000188fa6fc0 UIApplicationMain + 1152
15  App                             0x00000001000c8808 main (main.m:16)
16  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000192a73a9c start + 0

Thread 1 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000192b55aa8 kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000192a59998 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000192b55ca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185f36d20 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185f34eb0 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185e75dcc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   Foundation                      0x0000000186a6a424 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 344
5   Foundation                      0x0000000186af8408 __NSThread__main__ + 996
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192befe18 _pthread_body + 164
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192befd70 _pthread_start + 13
```

Comment: I am afraid it looks like you have a tough nut to crack. One thing that could be worth trying is to run the app in the debugger with a symbolic breakpoint in dispatch_mgr_thread and see if you can find something unexpected.